# Filterchain is not allowed to continue after async Firebase authentication

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, spring-boot, spring-security, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement custom authentication with firebase by adding a custom authentication filter and authentication provider. Both those seem to work fine but when the filterchain is supposed to continue an error is thrown and the request never reaches the controller. My application is using spring boot and is hosted on Google App Engine.

AuthenticationFilter

```
public class FirebaseFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static String HEADER_NAME = "X-Authorization-Firebase";

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String xAuth = request.getHeader(HEADER_NAME);

        if (StringUtil.isEmptyOrWhitespace(xAuth)) {

            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        } else {
            ApiFutures.addCallback(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdTokenAsync(xAuth),
                new ApiFutureCallback<FirebaseToken>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(FirebaseToken firebaseToken) {

                        FirebaseTokenHolder firebaseTokenHolder = new FirebaseTokenHolder(firebaseToken);

                        Authentication auth = new FirebaseAuthenticationToken(firebaseTokenHolder.getEmail(), firebaseTokenHolder);
                         SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);

                        try {
                            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
    }
}
```

AuthenticationProvider

```
@Component
public class FirebaseAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return (FirebaseAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
    }

    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        if (!supports(authentication.getClass())) {
            return null;
        }

        FirebaseAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = (FirebaseAuthenticationToken) authentication;

        Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
        grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("User"));

        UserDetails details = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(authenticationToken.getName(), "hello", grantedAuthorities);

        return new FirebaseAuthenticationToken(details, authentication.getCredentials(), details.getAuthorities());
    }

}
```

SpringBootExampleApplication

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebSecurity
@RestController
public class SpringBootExampleApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private FirebaseAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
               .and().addFilterBefore(new FirebaseFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
              .authorizeRequests()
                  .antMatchers("/", "/js/**") // Start page
                      .permitAll()
                  .anyRequest() // Everything that is not start-page is authenticated
                      .authenticated();//.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootExampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

When running this locally and sending a request to a endpoint that is supposed to be authenticated the try-catch in the callback-onsuccess in the filter throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.getRequestType(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:151)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:113)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1751)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.codaeasy.FirebaseFilter$1.onSuccess(FirebaseFilter.java:51)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.codaeasy.FirebaseFilter$1.onSuccess(FirebaseFilter.java:33)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onSuccess(ApiFutures.java:66)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$4.run(Futures.java:1132)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.firebase.internal.TaskToApiFuture$1.onComplete(TaskToApiFuture.java:50)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.firebase.tasks.OnCompleteCompletionListener$1.run(OnCompleteCompletionListener.java:54)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:435)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.firebase.tasks.OnCompleteCompletionListener.onComplete(OnCompleteCompletionListener.java:48)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.firebase.tasks.TaskCompletionListenerQueue.flush(TaskCompletionListenerQueue.java:81)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.firebase.tasks.TaskImpl.setResult(TaskImpl.java:95)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.firebase.tasks.Tasks$1.run(Tasks.java:82)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackgroundThreadFactory$1$1.run(BackgroundThreadFactory.java:60)
```

I've tried researching this error online but have not found anything.

Answer (score 1):

After trying a bit more I found out that in order for the filter to continue I have to wait for the Future to finish in the same thread for some reason. Instead of a callback I now have to following code in my filter

```
public class FirebaseFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static String HEADER_NAME = "X-Authorization-Firebase";

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String xAuth = request.getHeader(HEADER_NAME);

        if (StringUtil.isEmptyOrWhitespace(xAuth)) {

            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        } else {

            try {
                FirebaseToken token = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdTokenAsync(xAuth).get();
                System.out.println("Result in filter: " + token.getEmail());

                Authentication auth = new FirebaseAuthenticationToken(token.getEmail(), token);
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);

                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Im here");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```